# How can I fix 'brew cleanup' in Mac Big Sur?

Tags: macos, macos-big-sur, brew-doctor

I was trying to upgrade my Python in Mac's Big Sur OS. Due to the problem with 'brew' I was failing to upgrade my python. The problem was as follows-

I was trying to 'brew cleanup', it was giving me the following error:

(base) Muhammads-MacBook-Pro:~ muhammad$ `brew cleanup`
Error: Permission denied @ apply2files - /usr/local/share/ghostscript/9.16/Resource/CIDFont/HiraKakuPro-W3

Can anyone assist me to solve this problem? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Start with this thread : https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/45009

Comment: Or may be this one : https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/7732946

Comment: Since it's a permission issue, I suspect you are not running terminal as admin.